# Unresponsive Ubuntu install

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, crash

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 installation that sometimes becomes completely unresponsive have to hit the reset button. Usually when idle or under load. I check all the /var/log files and nothing looks out of place. I suspect NVIDIA drivers. Amd ryzen 7 1800x CPU. Help

Comment: How much RAM your PC has? It could be due to Maybe due to too much RAM usage. I used to have that kind of problem when all my RAM was used by programs like chrome browser.

Comment: I have 16 gigabytes of ram, I don't believe this is the problem as I would find errors in /var/logs would I not?

Comment: I've had similar issues. Ryzen 1700 and GTX 1080. Also 16GB ram. Do you have a multi-monitor setup? Do you get screen tearing when playing full-screen videos? What version of NVIDIA drivers?

Answer (score 0):

Found this regarding Ryzen Stability on Linux [https://cialu.net/how-to-make-a-ryzen-build-stable-on-linux/](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=196683)

[The issue on bugzilla](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=196683)

Haven't tried it yet the fix seems to involve fiddling with bios settings.

** **UPDATE** **

[Ryzen Segfaults](https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/9wyb84/ryzen_segfault_rma_still_valid_any_experiences/)

It seems a number of Gen 1 Ryzen Chips are inherently flawed and likely to produce segmentation faults specifically in Linux(or any unix-based kernel I assume).

You can test this with a simple script named at github [Kill_Ryzen](https://github.com/Oxalin/ryzen-test) which you can run from a live-(cd/usb/dvd).  I believe you can then RMA it to AMD for a replacement, not sure if the RMA is valid right now though.

** **Update #2** ** Solution?!?

For anyone with a first-generation Ryzen experiencing these issues, this solution 'should' work.

**Update Motherboard bios**,  Then set **Power Supply Idle Control** from 
**Auto** to **Typical Current Idle**.  The setting should but somewhere under CPU settings, possibly under overclocking.

Tracking with uptime 'tuptime' ( sudo apt install tuptime )

> Current uptime:         4 hours, 40 minutes and 3 seconds   since   05:55:31 PM 07/26/2019

We'll see it stays stable